# {since: gulp.lastRun('...')} не пропускает измененные файлы

Tags: gulp

Здравствуйте! 
Использую **Gulp 4**.
Никак не могу понять, почему `{since: gulp.lastRun('...')}` не пропускает в поток измененные файлы.
Добавляю, переименовываю файлы, **gulp.watch** срабатывает, но в потоке **0** файлов.
Без **since** всё работает корректно.
Подскажите, в чем может быть дело?

```js
gulp.task('assets', function() {
 return gulp.src('app/assets/**', {since: gulp.lastRun('assets')})
 .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
 gulp.watch('app/assets/**/*.*', gulp.series('assets')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Странно но 4 гальп все еще не в релизе. И похоже что since смотрит время модификации изображения и последнего запуска вашего таска. И даже если изображения нету в папке назначения оно его не скопирует из-за того что оно не менялось вообще. Как альтернативу могу предложить gulp-cached

Comment: Я уже не могу вспомнить, о чем этот вопрос, и что я имел ввиду. Помню только то, что я решил какую-то проблему с четвертым Галпом, прописав в package.json  строку `"gulp": "^4.0.0"`